# Address table applied to Users and Stores

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

On a database I have the following tables:

```
create table dbo.Stores ( 
  Id int not null
  Name nvarchar (120) not null
)

create table dbo.Users ( 
  Id int not null
  Name nvarchar (120) not null
)
```

Each User or Shop can have:
1 - One physical address;
2 - One website or social media addresses.

Should I have tables for Addresses and Social Media. For example:

```
create table dbo.Addresses ( 
  Id int not null
  Street nvarchar (120) not null,
  PostalCode nvarchar (12) not null
  City nvarchar (40) not null,
  Latitude float null,
  Longitude float null
)

create table dbo.UserAddresses ( 
  UserId int not null,
  AddressId int not null
)
```

And the same for Social Media, phone numbers and so on ...

Should I just add Columns to the Users table?

**Update 1**

For website addresses and social media addresses I am considering having the following:

```
create table dbo.UserWebAddresses ( 
  UserId int not null,
  WebAddressTypeId int not null,
  Value nvarchar(200) not null
)

create table dbo.WebAddressTypes ( 
  Id int not null,
  Name nvarchar(20) not null
)
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: I will point out that people and companies often have multiple addresses and far more than one social media account. Also float is terrible for storing latitude  (and longitude) since it is an inexact number and latitude and longitude are exact. You do not ever want rounding in those figures if you need them. Also you need country at a minimum and possibly State in your address table.  You may have users from other countries who border your country or who are there part-time.

Comment: @HLHEM About latitude and longitude I was considering using Decimal (9,6). What do you think?

Comment: @HLGEM About social media I can have many types of contacts ... Facebook, Twitter, etc ... I am considering having two tables: WebAddress and WebAddressType so one User could have many WebAddresses one of each type. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Add those columns directly to dbo.Stores and dbo.Users if there are no duplicated rows. If they might be duplicated, then create a new table and use FKs.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stores 
( 
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  Address_Id INT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users 
( 
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  Address_Id INT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Addresses 
( 
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Street NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  PostalCode NVARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  City NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  Latitude FLOAT NULL,
  Longitude FLOAT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Stores
  ADD CONSTRAINT Stores_Address_Id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Address_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Addresses(Id);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Users
  ADD CONSTRAINT Users_Address_Id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Address_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Addresses(Id);
```

We can also go with the following solution as well if I understood everything correct:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Stores 
( 
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  Address_Id INT NULL,
  Latitude FLOAT NULL,
  Longitude FLOAT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users 
( 
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  Address_Id INT NULL,
  Latitude FLOAT NULL,
  Longitude FLOAT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Addresses 
( 
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Street NVARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
  PostalCode NVARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  City NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Stores
  ADD CONSTRAINT Stores_Address_Id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Address_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Addresses(Id);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Users
  ADD CONSTRAINT Users_Address_Id_FK FOREIGN KEY (Address_Id) REFERENCES dbo.Addresses(Id);
```

Comment: As I see in comments, author has no idea of his design.
1. "Each User or Shop can have: 1 - One physical address; 2 - One website or social media addresses."
2. "so one User could have many WebAddresses one of each type"